# javascript do function after async data done

Tags: javascript

I have 3 json files (`machines, classes, subclasses`) which I receive by function `parsejson` and populate selectboxes and `objects`. Of course, the GetJSON function is asynchronous and the data does not come immediately, which causes further errors when im try to execute function `get_parts()`.
How can a `get_parts()` function be performed after three done execution `parsejson` functions?
im try to use async.. await construction, but tripple execution of `parsejson` functions does step by step and increases execution time, the code more fat and as the result, you have to repeat almost the same operations without functions.

```
var objects ={};
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    parsejson("machines", "#select_machines")
    parsejson("classes", "#select_classes")
    parsejson("subclasses", "#select_subclasses")
    get_parts("","1")
});

function parsejson(url, name, callback){
    let dropdown = $(name);
    dropdown.empty();
    dropdown.prop('selectedIndex', 0);
    // Populate dropdown with list of provinces
    $.getJSON(url).done( function (data) {
        objects[url] = data
        $.each(data, function (key, entry) {
            dropdown.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', entry.id).text(entry.name));
            $(name).selectpicker('refresh');
        })
    })
}

function get_parts(id, machine, classes, subclasses, description, count, vendor, location) {
    $("#parts_table_body").empty();
    $.post("parts",{id, machine, classes, subclasses, description, count, vendor, location},function(response){
        }).done(function(response) {
        varforresponse=response;
        for (i=0; i < varforresponse.length; i++){
            varforresponse[i].machine = objects.machines[varforresponse[i].machine].name;
            varforresponse[i].classes = objects.classes[varforresponse[i].classes].name;
            varforresponse[i].subclasses = objects.subclasses[varforresponse[i].subclasses].name;
        }
        $('#parts_table > tbody ').json2html(varforresponse, transform);
    });
}
```

regards

Comment: Call the function from `.done`.

Comment: @Teemu they won't be able to do it, the way it's written right now, because `parsejson` is called multiple times with different arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `parsejson` receives a callback but doesn't do anything with it
2. if `$.getJSON` is async you should declare `parsejson` as async and await on it
3. once you've implemented #2, you'll be able to do something like:

---

```
await parsejson("machines", "#select_machines")
await parsejson("classes", "#select_classes")
await parsejson("subclasses", "#select_subclasses")
await get_parts("","1")
```

**Sidenote**

In general it is recommended that the code will use async/await instead of using a mixture of callbacks and promise-chains!

The complete code should look something like this (not tested):

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", async () => {
    await parsejson("machines", "#select_machines")
    await parsejson("classes", "#select_classes")
    await parsejson("subclasses", "#select_subclasses")
    await get_parts("","1")
});

async function parsejson(url, name){
    let dropdown = $(name);
    dropdown.empty();
    dropdown.prop('selectedIndex', 0);
    // Populate dropdown with list of provinces
    const data = await $.getJSON(url);

    objects[url] = data
    $.each(data, function (key, entry) {
            dropdown.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', entry.id).text(entry.name));
            $(name).selectpicker('refresh');
    })
}

async function get_parts(id, machine, classes, subclasses, description, count, vendor, location) {
    $("#parts_table_body").empty();
    const response = await $.post("parts",{id, machine, classes, subclasses, description, count, vendor, location});

    varforresponse=response;
    for (i=0; i < varforresponse.length; i++){
        varforresponse[i].machine = objects.machines[varforresponse[i].machine].name;
        varforresponse[i].classes = objects.classes[varforresponse[i].classes].name;
        varforresponse[i].subclasses = objects.subclasses[varforresponse[i].subclasses].name;
    }
    $('#parts_table > tbody ').json2html(varforresponse, transform);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Promise.all` to wait till all 3 are resolve. Once done, you could do the processing.

```js
const [res1, res2, res3] = await Promise.all(parsejson("machines", "#select_machines"), parsejson("classes", "#select_classes"), parsejson("subclasses", "#select_subclasses"))

// res1 res2 and res3 contains result of these promises
// use accordingly
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var objects ={};
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", async () => {
    try {
        const p1 = parsejson("machines", "#select_machines");
        const p2 = parsejson("classes", "#select_classes");
        const p3 = parsejson("subclasses", "#select_subclasses");
        
        await Promise.all([p1, p2, p3]);
        
        await get_parts("","1");
        
        console.log('Done!');
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('operation failed', e);
    }
});

function parsejson(url, name, callback){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let dropdown = $(name);
        dropdown.empty();
        dropdown.prop('selectedIndex', 0);
        // Populate dropdown with list of provinces
        $.getJSON(url).done( function (data) {
            objects[url] = data
            $.each(data, function (key, entry) {
                dropdown.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', entry.id).text(entry.name));
                $(name).selectpicker('refresh');
            })
            
            resolve();
        }).fail(_ => reject());
    });
}

function get_parts(id, machine, classes, subclasses, description, count, vendor, location) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        $("#parts_table_body").empty();
        $.post("parts",{id, machine, classes, subclasses, description, count, vendor, location},function(response){
            }).done(function(response) {
            varforresponse=response;
            for (i=0; i < varforresponse.length; i++){
                varforresponse[i].machine = objects.machines[varforresponse[i].machine].name;
                varforresponse[i].classes = objects.classes[varforresponse[i].classes].name;
                varforresponse[i].subclasses = objects.subclasses[varforresponse[i].subclasses].name;
            }
            $('#parts_table > tbody ').json2html(varforresponse, transform);
        }).fail(_ => reject());
    });
}
```